# How to stop content jumping? (Typed js)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've written the following code for a static homepage. In this I want to use the library typed, which is include by the partial "head.html". But because of typed my content keeps jumping. This because at a certain point the subtitle container is empty. I've tried adding a default placeholder but this doesn't seem to fix the problem.

```js
particlesJS.load('particles-js', '/json/particlesjs-config.json', function() {
            console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
        });

        var typed = new Typed('#typed', {
          strings: ['First, solve the problem', 'Some <strong>HTML</strong>', 'Chars &times; &copy;'],
          typeSpeed: 0,
          backSpeed: 0,
          loop: true
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/particlesjs/2.2.2/particles.js"></script>

{{ partial "head.html" . }}
<section class="hero is-info is-medium">
  <div class="hero-head">
    {{ partial "navbar.html" .}}
  </div>

  <div id="particles-js"></div>

  <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container has-text-centered">
      <p class="title">

      </p>
      <p class="subtitle inline-block" id="typed">

      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hero-foot">
    <nav class="tabs is-boxed is-fullwidth">
      <div class="container">
        <ul>
          <li class="is-active">
            <a>Overview</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>Work</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>Grid</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
{{ partial "footer.html" .}}
```

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Well, your snippet has an error in it... `{
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: particlesJS is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 52,
  "colno": 9
}`

Answer (score 6):

I ran into a similar problem while trying to use Typed js. After doing some research, I fixed it by adding some css in my code. This might fix your problem.

In the code you provided, there are two errors. Firstly, you need to add a div tag around the p tag with `id="typed"` and as per the [docs](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/blob/master/README.md), the tag with `id="typed"` needs to be a span tag. Secondly, you need to add CSS to increase the height and padding.

Finally, it should Typed js parts should look like this:

```
<style>
  .text-body {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}
</style>

<div class="text-body">
    <span id="typed"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: the height and padding fixed it for me.

Comment: I fixed it by increasing the height.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to do following trick: to add invisible "cursor char", like this

```html
 <div class="container">
  <div id="typed-strings" style="display:none;">Text here</div>
  <span id="typed"></span>
  <span style="visibility:hidden;">|</span>
</div>
```